# Cannot stop JSSOR from pausing on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I'm trying to stop JSSOR from pausing on hover. I've checked through previous Q&A, but these are all concerned with getting it to hover, not stopping it!

I think I've got all the correct JSSOR settings and I've even tried to unbind **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** for the Slider Container, but nothing seems to work. This means that if the mouse is over the large slider container then it stops autoplay. I want autoplay to continue uninterrupted.

Here's the relevant code:

```
   //Define an array of slideshow transition code
var _SlideshowTransitions = [
{ $Duration: 1200, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2  }
];

var options = {
    $SlideDuration: 500,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
    $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $HoverToPause: false,                               //Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing
    $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
        $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
        $TransitionsOrder: 0,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
        $PlayOrientation: 1,                            //[Optional] Direction of play, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical
        $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Direction 0: no pause, 1: pause for desktop, 2: pause for touch device, 3: pause for
                                                        //           desktop and touch device, 4: freeze for desktop, 8: freeze for touch device, 
                                                        //           12: freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
        $ShowLink: false                                 //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
    }

};
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('SliderContainer', options);
```

and here's the HTML elements in question:

```
        <div id="SliderContainer" class="Slider">
        <div u="slides" class="SlideContainer">
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/01-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/06-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/02-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/03-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/07-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/04-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><img u="image" src="img/large-blinds/05-compressed.jpg"  alt="" />
                <div class="SlideTextContainer">
                    <div class="SlideText">Some Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd be grateful for any corrections to this to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the API details from JSSOR.

```
$PauseOnHover: 0,                               

//[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing,
0 no pause,
1 pause for desktop,
2 pause for touch device,
3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 3
```

Use as per requirement

and essentially for answer

```
$PauseOnHover: 0,
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you will see from my code **$PauseOnHover: 0** is already set. I've also tried it with and without **$HoverToPause: false**. Unfortunately neither of these commands stops it from pausing on hover.

Comment: @SimonFox I see in your code `$HoverToPause: false` , but not `$PauseOnHover: 0` as JSSOR API doc suggests, can you try with this, `$PauseOnHover: 0`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.

The problem was that $**PauseOnHover** had been defined inside the **$SlideshowOptions**  (See the original JSSOR code in my original question).

To get this to work I had to put it outside **$SlideshowOptions**:

```
    //Define an array of slideshow transition code
var SlideshowTransitions = [
{ $Duration: 1200, $SlideOut: true, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.3, $Opacity: 2  }
];

var options = {
    $SlideDuration: 1500,                           //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
    $DragOrientation: 1,                            //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
    $AutoPlay: true,                                //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
    $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                        //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
    $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Direction 0: no pause, 1: pause for desktop, 2: pause for touch device, 3: pause for
    $TransitionsOrder: 0,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
    $PlayOrientation: 1,                            //[Optional] Direction of play, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical
                                                    //           desktop and touch device, 4: freeze for desktop, 8: freeze for touch device, 
                                                    //           12: freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
    $ShowLink: true,                                //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false       
    $SlideshowOptions: 
    {                                               //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,             //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
        $Transitions: SlideshowTransitions,         //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
    }

};
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('SliderContainer', options);
```

The default action is to pause on hover, so incorrect placement of the variable meant that it used the default action.

The slide show now works properly and **no longer pauses on hover**.

I hope this is useful to others using JSSOR, which is an extremely useful and versatile slideshow tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can set,  **$PauseOnHover: 3** in the place of   $PauseOnHover: 0

```
$PauseOnHover: 3
```